# MySQL - Rearranging column with same values

Tags: mysql, sql

I found multiple threads with almost similar topic except one thing missing in those threads. I have a situation where I want to move position of a column (type -
 **ENUM('yes','no')**) - which can contain same values.

below is how the table rows look -

[image]

Now, how do I move 'column5' next to 'column2'?

I am using this query

```
 ALTER TABLE test_table MODIFY COLUMN column5 ENUM('yes','no') UNIQUE AFTER column2;
```

but it throws

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'yes' for key 'column5'

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Remove the `UNIQUE`.  The column is clearly *not* unique.

Comment: Why is it important?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - ah! That was dumb on my part. Thanks, didn't pay much attention there. It's fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either lose the "UNIQUE" you have before "AFTER", but it would just be easier to select them in the order you would like to see them?